# Cannot set installed locale with AWS Linux 2023

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, locale

I have a Python-based web app. that was deployed on an AWS Linux2 machine where I configured my locales properly. To show months and other amenities in the user's locale I have this line of code that worked perfectly:

```
from locale import LC_ALL, setlocale
from django.utils.translation import get_language

setlocale(LC_ALL, get_language().replace('-', '_'))
```

Now I migrated to the new Linux 2023 machine, and this line gives me the (in)famous error

```
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

I'm aware that locales must be installed and available, but the point is that (I think that) it already is: if I input

```
localectl list-locales
```

all the locales I need are there.

I also adapted them to the format they are shown in the output, *i.e.*,

```
get_language().replace('-', '_') + '.UTF-8'
```

but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What do you see when you run `echo $LC_ALL`?

Comment: Nothing, the variable is not set.